# group or count duplicated letters in elixir

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to count duplicated letters on a String in Elixir.
I did try some attempts, but no success until now.

Let's take this string as example: `"AAABBAAC"`

The desired output would be `"3A2B2A1C"`.

Converting this string to a `List`, I was able to count every letter, resulting in `"5A2B1C"`, but I have to count following the order.

This is the code I was doing:

```
string
|> String.graphemes
|> Enum.reduce([], fn(letter, acc) -> Keyword.update(acc, letter, 1, &(&1 + 1)) end)
```

But, in my tests, I'm trying to produce a List, like this `["AAA", "BB", "AA", "C"]`, so I can easely count with `String.lenght`.

Looks like using `Enum.chunk_by` I'm getting closer to a solution.

Is there a way to produce this?

Comment: Walk us through your logic. How are you trying to do this so far?

Comment: Are you working on this? http://exercism.io/exercises/elixir/run-length-encoding/readme

Comment: There is a nice recursive implementation here: https://github.com/pfac/elixir-run-length-encoder/blob/master/lib/run_length_encoder.ex

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci, don't know frostmage but this is a exercism exercise.

Comment: @vikram7 Already solved turning string in a list by `String.graphemes |> Enum.chunk_by(fn arg -> arg end) |> Enum.map(fn arg -> to_string(arg) end)`

Comment: @CoderDennis yes, exactly :) Already solved the encode part. Now I'm working on decode.

Comment: @tkowal Thanks. I think it can be done with much less code, but thanks for the tip :)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but here's a possible reason for it: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: Also, you might want to join the exercism room in Elixir on Slack. https://elixir-slackin.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Thanks @CoderDennis. The question is already solved, in my answer to this post. But I'll keep it in mind when asking another question. About slack, I'm already there :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you implement this using a recursive approach, you can easily keep track of the last occurred character and its current count, as well an accumulator that holds the result so far. If the current character equals the last character you just increase the count. If the two differ, you add the last character and its count to the accumulator and proceed with the next character until the string is empty. Finally, you encode the final value and return the result.

```
defmodule RunLengthEncoding do
  # public interface, take first char and remember it as the current value
  def encode(<<char::utf8, rest::binary>>) do
    do_encode(rest, char, 1, "")
  end

  # current == last, increase the count and proceed
  defp do_encode(<<char::utf8, rest::binary>>, char, count, acc) do
    do_encode(rest, char, count + 1, acc)
  end

  # current != last, reset count, encode previous values and proceed
  defp do_encode(<<char::utf8, rest::binary>>, last, count, acc) do
    do_encode(rest, char, 1, acc <> to_string(count) <> <<last::utf8>>)
  end

  # input empty, encode final values and return
  defp do_encode("", last, count, acc) do
    acc <> to_string(count) <> <<last::utf8>>
  end
end
```

Comment: It's a good answer, thanks. However, I was able to do the encode using much less code, improving readability.

Comment: I'm not sure that your solution is more readable @Hostert. Less lines of code is not automatically more readable.  Single character variables are shorter than longer names but they're hardly more readable.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Help Center > Answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), I did solve this way:

```
string
|> String.graphemes
|> Enum.chunk_by(fn arg -> arg end)
|> Enum.map(fn arg -> to_string(arg) end)
|> Enum.reduce("", fn(arg, acc) -> acc <> to_string(String.length(arg)) <> String.first(arg) end)
```

Now, explaining:

`String.graphemes` turns the `string` into a `List` containing every letter individually:

```
["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "C"]
```

`Enum.chunk_by(fn arg -> arg end)` groups every duplicate letters into new lists:

```
[["A", "A", "A"], ["B", "B"], ["A", "A"], ["C"]]
```

`Enum.map(fn arg -> to_string(arg) end)` brings it together again:

```
["AAA", "BB", "AA", "C"]
```

`Enum.reduce("", fn(arg, acc) -> acc <> to_string(String.length(arg)) <> String.first(arg) end)` finally concatenates the count (`String.length`) and the first letter (`String.first`) to initiall accumulator (`""`):

```
"3A2B2A1C"
```

Comment: Looks like a good solution, but you are building a lot of intermediate lists. That means this will perform worse than my approach, but if you're only dealing with small strings it will work just fine ;-)

Comment: @PatrickOscity thank for your feedback. Yes, it is just a little exercise on exercism.io. Not a big deal with performance and such things. As I'm a total newbie in Elixir, I'll start to deal with performance in a higher level, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below as well

```
"AAABBAAC" 
|> String.graphemes 
|> Enum.chunk_by(fn x -> x end) 
|> Enum.map(fn x -> [Enum.at(x,0), Enum.count(x)] end) 
|> List.flatten 
|> Enum.join
```