# Is there an analog of Python's Counter in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

You can count occurences of things with `Counter`. Also you can create counter from an iterable like this:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter("asdasdafasdasdasd")
Counter({'a': 6, 's': 5, 'd': 5, 'f': 1})
>>> Counter([1,2,3,2,1,2,2,5])
Counter({2: 4, 1: 2, 3: 1, 5: 1})
```

Comment: I think you could use `group_by` from the Enum module to implement something like this pretty fast.

Comment: This is almost a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36392742/group-or-count-duplicated-letters-in-elixir/36395321#36395321

Answer (score 3):

Not directly, but you can build it yourself using `Enum.reduce/3`

```
Enum.reduce values, %{}, fn(x, acc) ->
  Map.update(acc, x, 1, &(&1 + 1))
end
```

Comment: Only because people so often want to use piping in Elixir, an imperfect implementation of the same idea with piping: `values |> String.to_char_list |> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn (x, acc) -> Map.update(acc, x, 1, &(&1 + 1)) end)`  As I say, imperfect because the map has the character code rather than the character. Works ok otherwise.

Comment: I did about the same, but used List.foldl instead. Is that worse?

Comment: It's fine to use `List.foldl` if you have a small number of distinct elements. Since you are accumulating a list, you need to traverse the whole accumulator on each pass to find the previous count. This can be inefficient compared to map lookups.

Comment: As @OnorioCatenacci example shows, shouldn't the initial be 1 instead of 0? As the doc says, "If the key does not exist, inserts the given initial value."

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci, can also use `String.graphemes`

Answer (score 0):

```
> "asdasdafasdasdasd" |> String.graphemes |> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn (x, acc) -> Map.update(acc, x, 1, &(&1 + 1)) end)         
%{"a" => 6, "d" => 5, "f" => 1, "s" => 5}

> [1,2,3,2,1,2,2,5] |> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn (x, acc) -> Map.update(acc, x, 1, &(&1 + 1)) end)
%{1 => 2, 2 => 4, 3 => 1, 5 => 1}
```